# Is there a way to ignore a process in c# as a text file is being used by another process?

Tags: c#, text-files, magnetic-cards

Im trying to use magnetic swipe card machine to clock in users to a database i have everything working however my c# code that i use to read the text file which the swipe card software writes to pauses as the file is being used by another process, so i was wondering is their a way for my c# program?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have acces to the program that is using the text file?
if so you could solve this problem using

```
File.WriteAllLines()
```

this won't keep the file open.

read the file with

```
File.ReadAllLines()
```

Comment: string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\darren\Contacts\Desktop\staff.txt"); i am using this code to read the text file and change it and write to a different text file, however when my swipe card is using the text file to write to, the code pauses and waits for the swipe card to finish, i tried your method but couldnt get it to work at all, thans for your help